# Is there a way to set the window represented file in Tauri?

Tags: tauri

I am using Tauri with the vanilla-ts vite template.

Electron js allows you to set a window's [represented file](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/represented-file/) (macOS specific). Is there a way to accomplish this in Tauri?

I was expecting to find an option for it somewhere in the config [documentation](https://tauri.app/v1/api/config/), but it doesn't look like there's a way to do this.